# How to integrate Google Pay to flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, google-pay

I didn't find any popular libraries for this. Will it be possible to link native code with flutter?

Comment: It is possible in general to use native code in flutter. See [the documentation for platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#architecture). To receive a more useful answer you need to go into more detail on what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried already and what problems you encountered.

Comment: i am assuming you want to add in app purchase to your app if thats the case u can use https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase. And please provide with more details so any one can give you more suitable answer to your need

Comment: try this https://github.com/LeonidVeremchuk/flutter-google-pay

Answer (score 0):

Try this flutter package for google pay integration https://pub.dev/packages/google_pay/example